# Master-Detail with UITabBarItem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

Can you embed a Split-View Controller in a UITabBarController? I have a UITabBarController in my appdelegate on the window, and I tried adding a segue to my split view controller, but when I press the correlating tab for the DetailViewController it just shows a blank screen? Is it possible to even have a split-view controller as a tab in a tabbarcontroller?

[image: This is a picture of the storyboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UISplitViewController must be at the root of your controller hierarchy.  From Apple's [Split View Controllers](http://bit.ly/17O3EyZ) documentation:

> A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you
>   create. In other words, you must always install the view from a
>   UISplitViewController object as the root view of your application’s
>   window. The panes of your split view interface may then contain
>   navigation controllers, tab bar controllers, or any other type of view
>   controller you need to implement your interface. Split view
>   controllers cannot be presented modally